# How to execute a third party utility on every file in a folder recursively?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe, tesseract-ocr

I use a CLI utility called [tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki). The [tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki)'s usage in the cmd is this: `tesseract.exe imagename outputbase [options...] [configfile...]` In my case I type: `tesseract photo0043.jpg photo0043.txt -l Cyrillic` The utility will take the file called `photo0043.jpg` and output its job into the file called `photo0043.txt` How to make a batch to run the utility on an entire directory recursively?

Comment: This may be helpful - [Software to batch OCR multiple image files to multiple text files using Tesseract?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/53250/software-to-batch-ocr-multiple-image-files-to-multiple-text-files-using-tesserac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `.bat` file with the
[FOR /R](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) command to loop through files and
recurse on subfolders.

Something like:

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

For /R C:\path\to\folder %%a in (*.jpg) Do (
Set filename=%%~na
tesseract "%%a" !filename!.txt -l Cyrillic
)
```

Warning: I have not tested this script. It needs some tweaking if you have
`.jpg` files in subfolders of the specified folder.

Comment: I've surrounded the folder path and `%%~na` with double quotes and it worked but not for `.jpg` files in subfolders. Also, how to make it so that the output files are created in the same location where input files are because when I ran the batch everything was created in the root folder that was specified.

Comment: You could add the target path in the script in front of `!filename!.txt`. Might need enclosing in double quotes.

Comment: This does the job for me if anybody is interested..
`@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

For /R "C:\path\to\folder" %%a in (*jpg) Do (
Set filename="%%~dpna"
"tesseract" "%%a" !filename!.TESS -l Cyrillic
)`

Answer (score 0):

To batch convert a folder full of image files to a set of PDF files with searchable text I used the following in my version of a BAT file:

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

For /R N:\MaryImages %%a in (*.jpg) Do (
Set filename="%%~dpna" 
"tesseract" "%%a" !filename!.jpg -l eng PDF
)
```

Where N:\MaryImages is the path to the folder that contained the images I was working with on my Win7 PC.

Please replace "N:\MaryImages" with your folder path statement giving the location of the folder with you image files that need conversion to text searchable PDF files. Also the "(*jpg)" can be replaced with the file extension of your image files. [i.e. (*.png) etc]

Place your BAT file inside the folder where your images reside [as specified by your path]. Run it by double clicking on it. A temporary Command Line Window will launch and proceed to convert your files. Patiently wait till the CMD [CLI] window shuts down on its own. You will see a harvest of text searchable PDF files with each one having the reference name of its parent image file.

Use PDF-Xchange Editor to search the PDF text or combine all PDFs into one large PDF file. If sequentially scanned images were used with a proper sequence of the pages scanned from a book then PDF-Xchange editor will be able to reproduce the book without the loss of the sequence of the original pages with their embedded images, as tesseract OCRs and embeds the searchable text as a layer under the original text image portions. Each page will be broken up into separate text blocks just like any PDF file presents text.

The Image layer of the PDF page will contain the original scanned image.

Answer (score 0):

Use this batch file "PDF.bat" inside the folder where your series of image files reside.

Please change the folder "path" [J:\Russian*.jpg] to reflect you image folder location and also choose the language code singly or as a multiple language set [i.e. for English only : eng , for Russian only : rus or for Singahaese only : sin, if you want all three languages OCRed use eng+rus+sin in the bat file as I have done. You can download the "LANGUAGE.traineddata"codes from Github and install them into your
"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata" folder or where you have installed Tesseract.

My BAT file PDF.bat"" file is:

```
@Echo off
Set _SourcePath=J:\Russian\*.jpg
Set _OutputPath=J:\Russian\
Set _Tesseract="C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
For %%A in (%_SourcePath%) Do Echo Converting %%A...&%_tesseract% %%A %_OutputPath%%%~nA -l eng+sin+rus pdf
Set "_SourcePath="
Set "_OutputPath="
Set "_Tesseract="
```

Where "J:\Russian" is the folder where all my tri-lingual image files reside. The code "-l eng+sin+rus pdf" commands Tesseract to OCR a mixture of three languages "English Sinhalese and Russian" where the images contained a multiple of all three languages inside them.

Note: that "-l" is the  MINUS sign and the Lowercase Letter EL.

Tesseract can OCR : PNG TIFF BMP JPEG on many similar image formats and output PDF files with the OCR result text embedded in a layer behind the original image layer. If Pure image files or Image files with inbuilt non text images or blank spaces are present on the Image file, Tesserect will not OCR them and thereby overload data on to your HDD. It will OCR only the TEXT portion of the Image and do so keeping the relative positions of the Image text intact.

You can rename my PDF.bat batch file with any preferred name [anyname.bat] and run it by double clicking it inside the images folder. Wait till it runs the process. The output files will have the PDF file type ending with the original source file name.

My previous method in the preceding post has stopped working and I am unable to debug it. This new method is an updated version form another persons post an idea published on a superuser.com post I acknowledge his hard work Thank you!