# How to execute python script on every file recursively on windows

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

So I have a python command that takes a file path as a command line argument. Let's say `convert.py`.

On Linux I'm using the following script to run it on every file in a folder, recursively, using glob

```
for f in $1/**/*
do
  python ./convert.py $f
done
```

Which I can call like `sh ./script.sh src`.

Is there any way to do this on Windows?
I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1404590/how-to-execute-a-third-party-utility-on-every-file-in-a-folder-recursively) which is close but I didn't quite get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick idea is to use `Get-ChildItem` with the `-Directory` and `-Recurse`
options and use `Start-Process`  and its `-ArgumentList` option to execute the python script passing it the full directory path.

### 1. Simple script (use to test specific folder(s))

```
$src = "C:\Folder\Path";
(Get-ChildItem $src -Directory -Recurse).FullName | % { Process {
    Start-Process Python -ArgumentList "./convert.py $($_)" } };
```

---

### 2. PowerShell script with execution arg value

```
$src = $args[0]; 
(Get-ChildItem $src -Directory -Recurse).FullName | % { Process {
    Start-Process Python -ArgumentList "./convert.py $($_)" } };
```

> #### Executing the above #2 PowerShell script
>
> ```
> powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\PowerShell\PScript.ps1" "C:\Folder\123\678"
> ```

### 3. One more example (recursive files)

**Note:** In case the Python script needs the file path passed to it, use this example with the `-File` parameter this will pass the file paths. I'm not sure what the Python script is doing though.

```
$src = "C:\Folder\Path";
(Get-ChildItem $src -Recurse -File).FullName | % { Process {
    Start-Process Python -ArgumentList "./convert.py $($_)" } };
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)
- [Arrays](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [Start-process](https://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html)

Comment: My understanding is that [glob](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) and the wildcards are for directory paths and traversing to get full paths. Here are a couple equilevant PowerShell examples you might find helpful.

Comment: Just in case you do need the python script to be passed the full file paths rather than the path only, I added #3 example to show how that'd work.

Comment: why do you always use `Process{}` inside a `foreach`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer...while it's currently not working for me, I'm sure I'll be able to figure it out now that I have something to go on.

Comment: Got it working, I was referencing the file paths incorrectly and needed to remove the `- Directory` argument. Also needed to add the -NoNewWindow so that it doesn't open a hundred windows when I run the command. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @SimonS... It's out of habit and for a performance increase at times. Ever since I read up on it once per a comment someone left somewhere with a link, I've been doing that. I tested it out with `Measure-Command` for some loops and confirmed it indeed is faster in some instances. I think I do it out of habit more than anything now but I'm not aware of any issue is causes leaving it if it doesn't increase the speed. I read a better read on it once but cannot find, but see here for example https://powershell.one/tricks/performance/pipeline