# Is there a chmod +x equivalent in Windows 10, 11 to allow running scripts in Powershell/cmd with a specified shebang?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I would like to write cross platform scripts in some interpreted language (Python, Go, Node, whatever).

This is trivial in *nix systems (MacOS, Linux, BSD) as I just need to mark a file as executable using `chmod +x ./myfile` and the system will execute that script using the specified interpreter in the shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env python`). I can then run the file as though it were an executable using `./myfile`.

I would like to replicate this in Windows, however in Powershell running `.\myfile` attempts to open that file using the graphical OS "choose what application to run this with" dialog.

Is there an equivalent to `chmod +x ./myfile && ./myfile` in Windows or do I have to instruct people to use the full command (eg `python ./myfile`)?

Comment: No, windows uses file extensions to execute file types.  It will not look into the top line of a file to see what it should be executed in.  In addition, the chmod +x has nothing to do with the interpretation of the shebang.  NTFS certainly supports the +x concept through ACLs (access control lists) and always has.  On the flip-side, you *could* use WSL and write all of your scripts however you want (including bash).  A distro running under WSL ***IS*** Linux and can execute files from the windows side natively.   Also WSL is bad@$$.

Comment: Here's an example: `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\PowerShell\PScript.ps1"`. So you call Powershell.exe with necessary parameters and `-file <script>` will the be the full path to the ps1 file. Windows does not execute .ps1 file by design for security. So try the above example or `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\PowerShell\PScript.ps1" "scriptarg1"`. You can run `powershell.exe /?` to get more detail.

Comment: Here's an example answer I wrote, I'm sure I have tons of others as well as tons of others from others out there all over the place too https://superuser.com/questions/1656565/how-to-execute-python-script-on-every-file-recursively-on-windows/1656567#1656567

Comment: There is no need to make the files executable before running. If python is installed, then all your users need is the correct file extension to execute it from cmd or powershell like `.\myfile.py`

Answer (score 0):

The closest I know about is Get-ACL/Set-ACL

The equivalent NTFS permissions you need are "Traverse Folder / Execute File"

Example Code:

```
    $NewAcl = Get-Acl -Path "C:\Pets\Dog.txt"
    # Set properties
    $identity = "BUILTIN\Administrators"
    $fileSystemRights = "Traverse"
    $type = "Allow"
    # Create new rule
    $fileSystemAccessRuleArgumentList = $identity, $fileSystemRights, $type
    $fileSystemAccessRule = New-Object -TypeName 
    System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList 
    $fileSystemAccessRuleArgumentList
    # Apply new rule
    $NewAcl.SetAccessRule($fileSystemAccessRule)
    Set-Acl -Path "C:\Pets\Dog.txt" -AclObject $NewAcl
```

Set-ACL Documentation:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-acl?view=powershell-7.2

NTFS Permissions Documentation:
https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000137238/understanding-file-and-folder-permissions-in-windows

NTFS File System Rights Explanation:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights?view=net-6.0